# Detect touches and multitouch gestures on views and send them to the right receiver

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm facing a complex problem with my views, i will try to be as clear and specific as possible, if anything is unclear please say so.

I have a ScrollView containing a larger View (ContentView). I want this ScrollView to scroll using two (or more) finger swipes. In the contentView i have several instances of a custom view called barView. These barviews are similar to uisliders, but have some customisation. In order to be able to slide these barviews i use the "touchesMoved" method to track the touch. But whenever I want to scroll through the view using the multitouch swipe it also triggers the method on the barviews. How can i prevent the barviews from being manipulated by the multitouch swipe?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use PanGestureRecognizers to track the touches on the barViews. When setting them up you set:

```
[panGestureRecognzer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:scrollViewSwipeGestureRecognizer]
```

That ensures that the gestureRecognizers on your bar views can only trigger when the swiping gesture on the scrollview has failed.

Alternatively if your scrollView only scrolls when using 2 fingers, you could add the following to your barView's touchesMoved method:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count] > 1)
        return;
    /...
}
```

Comment: If have tried your second suggestion before, but sadly this method is very inaccurate, even if the users second touch comes very slightly after the first it triggers twice with count 1 instead of once with count 2.

Comment: Your first suggestion is going to be tricky because these recognizers dont live in the same class and are not applied on the same objects, but i'll see how far i get, thanks!